# Propagating client side events in .net user controls

Tags: javascript, .net, dom-events

I have a telerik rad tree view which I am wrapping in a user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ucAssetPicker.ascx.cs"Inherits="GPSOnline.UserControls.ucAssetPicker" %><%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<telerik:RadTreeView runat="server" ID="assetTreeView" Height="100%" Width="100%" Skin="Web20"
    DataFieldID="Id" DataFieldParentID="ParentId" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id"
    BorderStyle="None" SingleExpandPath="True" CausesValidation="False" 
    onnodeclick="assetTreeView_NodeClick" />
```

I was wondering if its possible to propagate a client side event from the tree view to the the page that is using my user control.

For example I would like to be able to respond to the `OnClientNodeClicked` event of the tree view in Javascript in the parent page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. If you check out their [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tree_clientonclientnodeclicked.html), they have an example that demonstrates how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yeah that's good except I want to be able to handle the event in java scrip in the parent not the usercontrol.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean. What is the parent?